# Array expression syntax error

Tags: arrays, syntax, compiler-errors, x86, nasm

i am trying to create an array with 5 data strings in it each comprised of 3 0's and a lowercase letter. When I go to compile my code it gives me an error for that line saying expression syntax is wrong. Is there something I am missing here? the line in the code is exactly as below

segment .data

my_data  db  000a, 000c, 000e, 000f, 000g ;skipped b,d due to use as binary and decimal notation

segment .text

code

edit *i have tried using db, dd, dw, dq to state size, none have worked. I tried noting the number of elements in the array.*

Comment: Is this nasm code? You should probably add a tag with the actual language or specify it in the question.

Comment: my apologies, yes it is x86 nasm. i'm in a PC Assembly/Machine Language course. I am running Ubuntu Linux Server in Oracle VirtualBox, if that is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are defined between quotes.  Below is an array of 7 stings including "b" and "d"

```
my_data db "000a", "000b", "000c", "000d", "000e", "000f", "000g"
```

Comment: thank you. i had tried that earlier and didnt think to try it again after making some changes. that fixed it.